# Jasper report remove/hide empty group

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

Background: Jaspersoft studio 6.

Have this crosstab:

[image]

The dataset for the crosstab:

```
    select 'prod1' as prod, 'mon1' as month, 1 as val
    union all select 'prod1' as prod, 'mon2' as month, 1 as val
    union all select 'prod2' as prod, 'mon1' as month, 1 as val
    union all select 'prod2' as prod, 'mon2' as month, 1 as val
    union all select 'prod3' as prod, null as month, null as val
```

The problem: as you may have noticed, prod3 has no data related to mon1 or mon2. But I will still need it to be showed in the report. So there is the null column being created by Jasper. How can I get rid of the null column?  I have tried blank when null or Remove line when blank at various places, but nothing works. Even at some point i can get rid of the null text but the cell is still being rendered so the borders and background colours still show.

And the source file (just a crosstab with one row group and one column group):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d00fbad1-be1e-4544-b22f-6dca803b6714">
    <style name="Crosstab_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CT" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#005FB3">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="Crosstab_CD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
            <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select 'prod1' as prod, 'mon1' as month, 1 as val
    union all select 'prod1' as prod, 'mon2' as month, 1 as val
    union all select 'prod2' as prod, 'mon1' as month, 1 as val
    union all select 'prod2' as prod, 'mon2' as month, 1 as val
    union all select 'prod3' as prod, null as month, null as val]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="prod" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="month" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="val" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="229" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab ignoreWidth="true">
                <reportElement x="10" y="14" width="520" height="116" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="bb1bb352-1dab-438b-b2c8-b73286af3a9c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.layout" value="com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.layout.VerticalRowLayout"/>
                </reportElement>
                <rowGroup name="prod1" width="60">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{prod}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="d56c7426-8030-4919-8869-86129c230a48"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{prod1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="ef3d9aab-f696-48c4-b95b-6be099951c55"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total prod1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="month1" height="20">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{month}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CH">
                            <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="f8dca50f-1f98-425b-bc4e-8a9505901477"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{month1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="4960b0b9-4df7-4216-908e-e042ccf2e3a6"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Total month1]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="val_MEASURE1" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{val}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CD">
                        <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" uuid="d207dcd9-1db6-4adb-a7ba-1b539fa06993"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{val_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" columnTotalGroup="month1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="59ff8664-202c-4ec7-966c-93c30b372202"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{val_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="prod1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="686e7851-9a94-4cbe-aac1-60703fdfc049"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{val_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="60" height="20" rowTotalGroup="prod1" columnTotalGroup="month1">
                    <cellContents mode="Opaque" style="Crosstab_CT">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="60" height="20" forecolor="#FFFFFF" uuid="acbe85bf-5cea-40d3-9951-cb0de8baa353"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{val_MEASURE1}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: what about filter out in sql or java level ?

Comment: What you mean? I don't want to filter out prod3, I want it to be there in the report, just shows 0  for mon1 and mon2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got this solved. Nothing to do with Jasper (it's a good tool but to be honest it just lacks some features). The solution is simply give prod3 a column group and 0 value. The key is simply do not have null value for any group field so that Jasper can't  generate a null group. For this case, just give prod3 value of any existing group member (mon1 or mon2) and 0 value. For a real case, there has to be some sql messing to achieve this, but which is far more easier than hacking with jasper.

```
    select 'prod1' as prod, 'mon1' as month, 1 as val
        union all select 'prod1' as prod, 'mon2' as month, 1 as val
        union all select 'prod2' as prod, 'mon1' as month, 1 as val
        union all select 'prod2' as prod, 'mon2' as month, 1 as val
        union all select 'prod3' as prod, 'mon1' as month, 0 as val
```